# Adding parse to xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, back4app

I'm following [this toturial](https://www.back4app.com/docs/ios/parse-swift-sdk) to add parse to my ios project.

I came till this step:

[image: step]

I don't understand what they saying about changing the path I went to "Build Settings" and inside "Runpath Search Paths" I see: `$(inherited) @executable_path/Frameworks`, what should I cheange?

[image: change]

Here my app location:

[image: chatlocation]

Plz shre with me what you think I should write in this path.

Comment: Did you install Parse with the CocoaPods package manager, as described in the tutorial?

Comment: Yes, I made all steps, until the point of the screenshot  @dr_barto

Comment: Usually when you use CocoaPods, there are no additional manual steps required. Just make sure not to open the project file (`.xcodeproj`)  but the workspace file generated by CocoaPods (`.xcworkspace`), then you should be able to import Parse in your own code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read the *Be careful* advice carefully. It talks about **`Search Paths > Framework Search Paths`**

[image]

not `Linking > Runpath Search Paths`

There add the two paths

[image]

Of course it assumes that the Parse framework is already installed.